# Maple: How to convert Cylindrical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: coordinates, maple, cartesian, cylindrical

We get some expression in [Cylindrical coordinates (r, ϕ, z )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) like : `expr := r*z^2*sin((1/3)*`ϕ`)` we need to convert it into [Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) and than back to Cylindrical coordinates. How to do such thing?

So I found something like this : `eval(expr, {r = sqrt(x^2+y^2), z = z,`ϕ`= arctan(y, x)})` but it seems incorrect, how to correct it and how make eval to convert backwords from Cartesian  to Cylindrical?

`&varphi;` == ϕ

So I try:

```
R := 1; 

H := h; 

sigma[0] := sig0;

sigma := sigma[0]*z^2*sin((1/3)*`&varphi;`);

toCar := eval(sigma, {r = sqrt(x^2+y^2), z = z, `&varphi;` = arctan(y, x)});

toCyl := collect(eval(toCar, {x = r*cos(`&varphi;`), y = r*sin(`&varphi;`), z = z}), `&varphi;`)
```

It looks close to true but look: [image]

why `arctan(r*sin(`ϕ`), r*cos(`ϕ`))` is not shown as ϕ?

Actually it is only begining of fun time for me because I also need to calculate

```
Q := int(int(int(toCar, x = 0 .. r), y = 0 .. 2*Pi), z = 0 .. H)
```

and to get it back into Cylindrical coordinates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
simplify(toCyl) assuming r>=0, `&varphi;`<=Pi, `&varphi;`>-Pi;
```

Notice,

```
arctan(sin(Pi/4),cos(Pi/4));
                          1   
                          - Pi
                          4   

arctan(sin(Pi/4 + 10*Pi),cos(Pi/4 + 10*Pi));
                          1   
                          - Pi
                          4   

arctan(sin(-7*Pi/4),cos(-7*Pi/4));
                          1   
                          - Pi
                          4   

arctan(sin(-15*Pi/4),cos(-15*Pi/4));
                          1   
                          - Pi
                          4   


arctan(sin(-Pi),cos(-Pi));
                           Pi

K:=arctan(r*sin(Pi/4),r*cos(Pi/4));
                      arctan(r, r)

simplify(K) assuming r<0;
                           3   
                         - - Pi
                           4   

simplify(K) assuming r>0;
                          1   
                          - Pi
                          4
```

Once you've converted from cylindrical to rectangular, any information about how many times the original angle" might have wrapped around (past -Pi) is lost.

So you won't recover the original `&varphi;` unless it was in (-Pi,Pi]. If you tell Maple that is the case (along with r>-0 so that it knows which half-plane), using assumptions, then it can simplify to what you're expecting.

Comment: so... top line still gives me `arctan(sin(`&varphi;`), cos(`&varphi;`))` please see post update.

Comment: It works for me, provided that the mentioned assumption is supplied.